# geometry nodes, remove instance top to bottom

Tags: geometry-nodes

is it possible to randomly delete instance from top to bottom?
tried some stuff but was only removing geometry and not instances
created that small geometry node setup to scatter object on a curve but i would like to randomly remove instance on the z axis (like using a ramp)
thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: since we have no idea, how your GN tree looks like, you maybe wanna share your node tree with us via image or blend file? maybe this helps:https://youtu.be/ZleGuOP3Rpk

Comment: See this: [How to make disintegration or dissolve effect from center of the object with texture or geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/298187/60486) - specifically the Quellenform's answer. You could add a random value to the distance calculation (in your case height) to mix between randomness and from top-to-bottom transition.

Comment: makes sense^^ just added a screenshot of simplified version of the setup but its basically the same just adding some randomness to the instance, i m new to this and maybe i m doing things the wrong way, i use the duplicate elements to create some sort of wall and would like to be able to remove points at the top to create randomness to it

Answer (score 1):

[image]

With the following node setting:

[image]

In this example the top instance is unstacked every one second.

It adds delta time of the simulation zone and check if more 1 second elapse is spent.

If yes, it gets the topmost instance, using an attribute statistics looking at max Z position value and delete the corresponding instance(s).

Comment: awesome gonna try that thanks!
stupid question how do you get the cumulated time input in the simulation input/output?

Comment: just add a float input, for instance from the n panel once the group input is selected. Note that you provided a very partial information about your node setting, so, this answer may work directly or may need to be adapted.

Comment: thanks! here is the file (simplified the nodes but its the base)
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ycvtmyexh1o6kfufsmurz/geonodes-curve-clean-light.blend?rlkey=tn5lt0rtsbqt544cydzf7oso3&dl=0
like i said pretty new with all that and just trying stuff out with what i find online, so if you have tips to make it better dont hesitate :)

Comment: Your file with the "unstack" + some randomness, if that can help: https://blend-exchange.com/b/w0mDP0xg/

Comment: awesome man thanks!